Unwanted Audit and Unexpected Audit Insert with Hibernate
I have a couple of related entities, Person and PersonPreference:
public class PersonPreference {
  @Id
  private Long id;

  @EntityId(value = Person.class, defer = false)
  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "PERSON", nullable = false, insertable = true, updatable = false)
  @SensitiveData
  private Person person;
}

public class Person {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(generator = MY_SEQUENCE_GENERATOR_NAME, strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
  @SequenceGenerator(name = MY_SEQUENCE_GENERATOR_NAME, sequenceName = MY_SEQUENCE_GENERATOR_NAME, allocationSize = 1)
  private Long id;

  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "person")
  private List<PersonPreference> personPreferences = new ArrayList<>(0);
}

I am using Envers.
My use case is that Person already exists on the Database and I am persisting a PersonPreference.
Patient existingPerson = EM.find(Person.class, personId);
personPreference.setPerson(existingPerson);
EM.persist(personPreference);
EM.flush();

This is resulting in

Insert to Person_Preference
Insert to Z_Person_Preference (audit table)
Insert to Z_Person (audit table)

I am at a loss as to why that insert to the Z_Person audit table is occurring. The Person entity has not changed, and that additional insert is just a duplicate of the last legitimate audit record for person.
How do I stop insert number 3?

The solution to this was to add @NotAudited to the PersonPreference.person field.
